# jQuery: delete objects from JSON array stored in localstorage?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm creating a simple shopping cart based on jQuery.

Everything works so far.

However, I now need to allow the users to delete items that they've added to the basket.

I can delete the item and it works but it will only work **ONCE** and then it starts behaving strangely which doesn't make sense!

To explain this, I've created this minified FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/zmbpk1tr/6/

If you open the link above and click on any of the '*Green buttons*', that element should be deleted and if you try to delete any other ones after that, you should see the issue.

The code for deleting is this:

```
//////// We try to delete the element here if its clicked on//////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$(document).on('click','.cart-del',function(e){



    $('.cart-del').remove();

    var timeAttr = $(this).attr('data-time');

    alert(timeAttr);

    var result = parsedObject.filter(function(x){return x.timeStamp !== timeAttr; });



    var setLoc = JSON.stringify(result);
    localStorage.setItem('product', setLoc);


    var retrievedObject2 = localStorage.getItem('product');



    var parsedObject2 = JSON.parse(retrievedObject2);


            $.each(parsedObject2, function(pi,item){ 

                var products = '<div class="cart-del" id="'+item.id+'" data-price="'+item.price+'" data-details="'+item.details+'" data-time="'+item.timeStamp+'" id="1" data-price="20">'+
'<p>Delete "'+item.id+'"</p>'+
'</div>';



               $(".endDiv").before(products);


});

    });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it too simple to just put this at the top of your on click() listener?
$(this).remove(); return true;  The reason I ask is I assume you're sending AJAX to update something in your backend?

Comment: @AaronBelchamber, thanks for the reply mate. I'm not sending anything via AJAX though (not at this stage). The answer given by Daniel worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the array from localStorage every time you click.

```
$(document).on('click','.cart-del',function(e){
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('product');
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

    $('.cart-del').remove();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In your fiddle, `parsedCode` is outside the scope of the click event and contains the 3 elements, and you keep filtering items from that array, so that causes the "strange" behaviour.

Comment: This is nice, but I still wonder why $(this).remove(); return true; wouldn't be all you needed to do here?  No access of anything you just click button and it goes away.

Comment: But that wouldn't remove the cart item from localStorage. The above code would only work to remove the button from the DOM.